# Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.Base.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize'

Tags: android, android-studio, resources, android-appcompat, aviary

I Have integrated Aviary SDK in my Project.
I am using Android Studio.

I have also integrated the Appcompact V7 still i am 
getting the following error:

**Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.Base.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize'.**

Please Help me guys with your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem when I started adding Aviary into the project I´m working on.

Finally I´ve managed to solve it by changing the style adding an extra line due to I didn´t wanted to change any line code from Aviary:

```
<style name="Theme.Base.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize">        
    </style>
```

it seems that  **Base** has been add so it  changes completely the style name.

Before was *Theme.Base.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize* and now is **Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize**

btw, I´ve also changed my theme to:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

I hope this help you to solve the problem.

Comment: thak you for valubale Input. Let me try this and will get back to you on monday.

Comment: Are you saying that I should change the error on Theme.Base.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize to Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize?

Comment: What I'm saying @jeraldo, it is that If you have this error due to the Style **Theme.Base.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize** is not available. You can solve it by extend the style **Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize** which is the same one but with different Parent.

Comment: Aviary is now AdobeCreativeSDK and Using this new SDK of ADOBE solved my issue.

Comment: Thank you for this! Spent hours trying to find the solution to this and your solution worked!!

Answer (score 5):

copy below code in your style file...

```
  <style name="AviaryBaseTheme.Dark.Dialog" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize">
    <item name="aviaryFontRegular">fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf</item>
    <item name="aviaryFontLight">fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf</item>
    <item name="aviaryTextAppearance">@style/AviaryTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="aviaryTextAppearanceLarge">@style/AviaryTextAppearance.Large</item>
    <item name="aviaryTextAppearanceLargeNoSelection">@style/AviaryTextAppearance.Large.NoSelected</item>
    <item name="aviaryTextAppearanceMedium">@style/AviaryTextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="aviaryTextAppearanceMediumNoSelection">@style/AviaryTextAppearance.Medium.NoSelected</item>
    <item name="aviaryTextAppearanceSmall">@style/AviaryTextAppearance.Small</item>
    <item name="aviaryTextAppearanceSmallNoSelection">@style/AviaryTextAppearance.Small.NoSelected</item>
    <item name="aviaryTextAppearanceInverted">@style/AviaryTextAppearance.Inverted</item>
    <item name="aviaryTextAppearanceLargeInverted">@style/AviaryTextAppearance.Inverted.Large</item>
    <item name="aviaryTextAppearanceMediumInverted">@style/AviaryTextAppearance.Inverted.Medium</item>
    <item name="aviaryTextAppearanceSmallInverted">@style/AviaryTextAppearance.Inverted.Small</item>
    <item name="aviaryDefaultTextStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.TextView</item>
    <item name="aviaryPrimaryButtonStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.Button</item>
    <item name="aviarySecondaryButtonStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.Button.Secondary</item>
    <item name="aviaryLightGrayButtonStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.Button.LightGray</item>
    <item name="aviaryToggleButtonStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.Button.Secondary.Toggle</item>
</style>
<style name="AviaryTheme.Dark.Dialog" parent="AviaryBaseTheme.Dark.Dialog"/>
<style name="AviaryTheme.Dark1" parent="AviaryBaseTheme.Dark.NoActionBar">
    <item name="aviaryBackgroundColor">@color/aviary_background_color</item>

    <!-- custom widgets styles -->
    <item name="aviarySeekBarStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.AviarySeekBar</item>
    <item name="aviaryWheelStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.AviaryWheel</item>
    <item name="aviaryTiltShiftViewStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.TiltShiftView</item>
    <item name="aviarySymbolMinusStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.SymbolMinus</item>
    <item name="aviarySymbolPlusStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.SymbolPlus</item>

    <item name="aviaryEdgeEffectDefaultStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.EdgeEffect</item>

    <item name="aviaryAdjustImageViewStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.AdjustImageView</item>
    <item name="aviaryAdjustDividerWeight">@integer/aviary_adjust_divider_weight</item>
    <item name="aviaryAdjustItemWeight">@integer/aviary_adjust_item_weight</item>

    <!-- bottombar styles -->
    <item name="aviaryBottomBarHeight">@dimen/aviary_bottombar_height</item>
    <item name="aviaryBottomBarViewFlipperStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.BottomBar.ViewFlipper</item>
    <item name="aviaryBottomBarOptionPanelStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.BottomBar.OptionPanel</item>
    <item name="aviaryBottomBarOptionPanelContainerStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.BottomBar.OptionPanelContainer</item>
    <item name="aviaryBottomBarOptionPanelContainerStyleNoMargin">
        @style/AviaryWidget.BottomBar.OptionPanelContainer.BorderLess
    </item>

    <item name="aviaryBottomBarToolStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.BottomBar.Tool</item>
    <item name="aviaryBottomBarToolFeedBackStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.BottomBar.Tool.FeedBack</item>
    <item name="aviaryBottomBarToolImageStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.Tool</item>
    <item name="aviaryBottomBarToolTextStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.TextView.Tool</item>

    <item name="aviaryHighlightImageButtonStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView</item>
    <item name="aviaryLensViewStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.Lens</item>

    <!-- option panel styles -->
    <item name="aviaryOptionPanelDefaultButtonStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.OptionPanelButton</item>
    <item name="aviaryOptionPanelToggleButtonStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.OptionPanelButton.Toggle</item>
    <item name="aviaryOptionPanelToggleLeftButtonStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.OptionPanelButton.Toggle.Left
    </item>
    <item name="aviaryOptionPanelToggleCenterButtonStyle">
        @style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.OptionPanelButton.Toggle.Center
    </item>
    <item name="aviaryOptionPanelToggleRightButtonStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.OptionPanelButton.Toggle.Right
    </item>

    <!-- adjust panel button styles -->
    <item name="aviaryAdjustOptionPanelToggleLeftButtonStyle">
        @style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.OptionPanelButton.Toggle.Left.Adjust
    </item>
    <item name="aviaryAdjustOptionPanelToggleRightButtonStyle">
        @style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.OptionPanelButton.Toggle.Right.Adjust
    </item>

    <!-- ehance panel buttons style -->
    <item name="aviaryEnhanceOptionPanelToggleLeftButtonStyle">
        @style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.OptionPanelButton.Toggle.Left.Enhance
    </item>
    <item name="aviaryEnhanceOptionPanelToggleCenterButtonStyle">
        @style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.OptionPanelButton.Toggle.Center.Enhance
    </item>
    <item name="aviaryEnhanceOptionPanelToggleRightButtonStyle">
        @style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.OptionPanelButton.Toggle.Right.Enhance
    </item>
    <item name="aviaryEnhanceItemWeight">@integer/aviary_enhance_item_weight</item>

    <!-- focus panel buttons style -->
    <item name="aviaryFocusOptionPanelToggleLeftButtonStyle">
        @style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.OptionPanelButton.Toggle.Left.Focus
    </item>
    <item name="aviaryFocusOptionPanelToggleRightButtonStyle">
        @style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.OptionPanelButton.Toggle.Right.Focus
    </item>

    <!-- color splash option panel button styles -->
    <item name="aviaryColorSplashOptionPanelToggleButtonStyle">
        @style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.OptionPanelButton.Toggle.TiltShift
    </item>
    <item name="aviaryColorSplashOptionPanelToggleLeftButtonStyle">
        @style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.OptionPanelButton.Toggle.Left.TiltShift
    </item>
    <item name="aviaryColorSplashOptionPanelToggleRightButtonStyle">
        @style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.OptionPanelButton.Toggle.Right.TiltShift
    </item>

    <item name="aviarySplashDividerWeight">@integer/aviary_color_splash_divider_weight</item>
    <item name="aviarySplashItemWeight">@integer/aviary_color_splash_item_weight</item>

    <!-- navigation styles -->
    <item name="aviaryNavBarStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.NavBar.Main</item>
    <item name="aviaryNavTitleStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.TextView.NavTitle</item>
    <item name="aviaryNavButtonStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.Button.NavButton</item>
    <item name="aviaryNavButtonApplyStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.Button.NavButton.Apply</item>

    <!-- spot toast and drawables -->
    <item name="aviaryPreviewSpotDrawableStyle">@style/AviaryGraphics.PreviewSpot</item>
    <item name="aviaryPreviewSpotViewStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.PreviewSpot</item>

    <!-- fill drawable and toast style -->
    <item name="aviaryPreviewFillDrawableStyle">@style/AviaryGraphics.PreviewFill</item>

    <item name="aviaryGalleryStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.AviaryGallery</item>
    <item name="aviaryGalleryTopIndicatorStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.BottomBar.GalleryTopIndicatorView</item>
    <item name="aviaryGalleryBottomIndicatorStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.BottomBar.GalleryTopIndicatorView.Inverse</item>
    <item name="aviaryOptionPanelTopIndicatorStyle">@style/AviaryGraphics.GalleryTopIndicator</item>
    <item name="aviaryOptionPanelBottomIndicatorStyle">@style/AviaryGraphics.GalleryTopIndicator.Inverse</item>
    <item name="aviaryOptionPanelBottomLineStyle">@style/AviaryGraphics.GalleryBottomLine</item>

    <item name="aviaryMemeButtonStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.Button.Meme</item>
    <item name="aviaryMemeClearButtonStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.HighlightImageView.Clear</item>

    <item name="aviaryGalleryItemContainerStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.BottomBar.GalleryItem.Container</item>
    <item name="aviaryGalleryItemDividerStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.BottomBar.GalleryItem.Divider</item>
    <item name="aviaryGalleryItemHighlightImageStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.BottomBar.GalleryItem.HighlightImageView</item>
    <item name="aviaryGalleryItemCropTextNormalStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.BottomBar.GalleryItem.Crop.TextView</item>
    <item name="aviaryGalleryItemCropTextCustomStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.BottomBar.GalleryItem.Crop.TextView.Custom</item>
    <item name="aviaryGalleryItemCropImageViewStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.BottomBar.GalleryItem.Crop.HighlightImageView</item>

    <item name="aviaryNavDividerStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.NavBar.Divider</item>

    <item name="aviaryMainImagePadding">@dimen/aviary_main_image_padding</item>
    <item name="aviaryPanelDisabledStatusBackground">@color/aviary_panel_disabled_status</item>
    <item name="aviaryHiddenEditTextStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.HiddenText</item>
    <item name="aviaryHiddenEditTextStyleMultiline">@style/AviaryWidget.HiddenText.TextTool</item>

    <!-- effects and frames -->
    <item name="aviaryEffectThumbDividerRightContainerStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.EffectThumb.DividerContainer</item>
    <item name="aviaryEffectThumbDividerLeftContainerStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.EffectThumb.DividerContainer.Left</item>

    <item name="aviaryEffectThumbDividerRightStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.EffectThumb.Divider</item>
    <item name="aviaryEffectThumbDividerLeftStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.EffectThumb.Divider.Left</item>
    <item name="aviaryEffectThumbDividerStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.EffectThumb.PacksDivider</item>
    <item name="aviaryEffectThumbDividerTextStyle">@style/AviaryGraphics.PluginDividerText</item>

    <!-- Feedback -->
    <item name="aviaryFeedbackDialogStyle">@style/AviaryDialog.MainLayout</item>
    <item name="aviaryFeedbackDialogTextVersionStyle">?aviaryDefaultTextStyle</item>
    <item name="aviaryFeedbackDialogDividerStyle">@style/AviaryDialog.Divider</item>
    <item name="aviaryFeedbackDialogTextMessageStyle">@style/AviaryDialog.Feedback.Text</item>

    <!-- buttons for the custom dialogs ( feedback, about, ... ) -->
    <item name="aviaryCustomDialogButtonStyle">?aviaryPrimaryButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="aviaryCustomDialogButtonSecondaryStyle">?aviarySecondaryButtonStyle</item>

    <!-- toast loader -->
    <item name="aviaryLoaderToastStyle">@style/AviaryWidget.ModalToastLoader.MainView</item>
    <item name="aviaryToastExitAnimation">@anim/aviary_toast_exit</item>

    <item name="hlv_listPreferredItemWidth">64dip</item>
</style>
```

and the make below changes in your manifest.....

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.aviary.android.feather.sdk.FeatherActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:process=":aviarysdk"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
        android:theme="@style/AviaryTheme.Dark1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional info for Lechon's answer.
I think you have to update compileSdkVersion, buildToolVersion of Aviary-SDK. It should be later than 21. Then it worked.

build.gradle

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
    //...
    }
```