# add aviary sdk 3.6.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, aviary

I'm trying to compile with this gradle to add aviary sdk to my project

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
    apply plugin: 'realm-android'
    apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "..."
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        signingConfigs {
            release {
                ...
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/brendanw/maven/' }
        maven { url 'https://clojars.org/repo/' }
        maven { url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
            name 'maven.aviary.com'
            url uri("http://maven.aviary.com/repo/release")
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        // Compatibility
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

        // Play services API
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1'

        // Map Utils
        compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'

        // Realm.io
        compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0'

        // Stetho
        compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
        compile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:0.9.0'

        // Firebase
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'

        // Parceler
        compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.1'
        apt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.1'

        // Events
        compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

        // Network
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'

        // Data Verification
        compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:5.5'

        // Image Loading
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

        // Annotations
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
        compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA'
        compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

        // Views
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
        compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
        compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.3.4'

        // Logging
        compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.1'
        compile 'com.jaredrummler:android-device-names:1.0.9'

        // Barcode
        compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'

        // Facebook
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'

        // Payment
        compile 'me.brendanweinstein:paymentkit-droid:1.0.4'
        compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.4'

        //fabric
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }

        //adobe
        compile 'com.aviary.android.feather.sdk:aviary-sdk:3.6.3'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and i have some errors on values compiled file..

```
C:\Users\OLENGO\Desktop\Remy\android-printogo\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml

Error:(1562) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.Base.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize'.
```

I already try with this sample : https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/blob/master/image-editor-ui/guide/image-editor.markdown

but if i upgrade the compileSdkVersion, even the sample have some errors

Does anyone else had such problem, and is there any way to avoid this crash?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739560/errorerror-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given)

Comment: ... i'm felling bad to didn't find this

Thanks a lot.

Comment: check this answer I did time ago http://stackoverflow.com/a/27875039/1873390